# Editing a wrong problem in geometry

Tags: geometry

I got this problem from a geometry book:

In cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$, $E$ is a midpoint of $AB$. Perpendicular drawn from $E$ to $AB$ intersects $BC$ at $X$ and perpendicular drawn from $E$ to $DC$ intersects $AD$ in $Y$ prove that if $XY$ intersects $AD$  at $O$ then $XOY=90$.

The problem seems wrong could anyone suggest an edit for making it true?

Comment: Indeed, by definition, $X, O$ and $Y$ are aligned !

Comment: Little rectification, not of the problem but about the use of definite/undefinite article in "*a* midpoint of AB" which should be "*the* midpoint of AB", just because it is unique...

Answer (score 0):

Point $Y$ is defined to be on $AD$ so saying that $XY$ intersects $AD$ at $O$ means that $O$ and $Y$ are the same point. I think what needs to be proven is that $XY$ is perpendicular to $AD$. I'd express that directly and omit point $O$ entirely.

I also think that the way the perpendiculars are described is unclear, so I'd reword those parts. Something like:

> In cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$, the perpendicular bisector of segment $AB$ intersects $AB$ at $E$ and intersects $BC$ at $X$. The perpendicular drawn from $DC$ through $E$ intersects $AD$ at $Y$.
>
> Prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are not concurrent then $XY$ is perpendicular to $AD$.

It's difficult to be certain that this is the intended interpretation, but it does involve proving a $90^\circ$ angle, and a quick play on GeoGebra suggests that this is indeed true. Example:

[image]

Comment: Could you also prove the problem?